# Alternativas al DOMPDF

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, ya he pasado demasiado tiempo con el problema de no poder imprimir documentos PDF en mi proyecto Laravel.
Por ello, me gustaria saber si existen alternativas a DOMPDF, el metodo que uso para imprimir PDF en Laravel, a ver si con otro metodo logro imprimir en PDF.

He hablado ya de este problema en otras de mis preguntas, pero os muestro mi mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mi código:

```
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF;

public function imprimir(Juego $j){
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.juego', compact('j'));
        $salida=$pdf->output();
        $ruta='C:/Users/pcx/Desktop/Juego '.$j->numero.' '.$j->nombre.'.pdf';
        file_put_contents($ruta, $salida);
        return back()->with('message',['success','El PDF con los datos del juego se han creado con exito. Buscalo en tu escritorio.']);
}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta esta basada en opiniones, deberías de publicar el error que tienes y no así solo otra alternativa, ya que DOMPDF se integra de excelente forma en Laravel.

Comment: @Shassain He añadido más información.

Comment: Verifica que estas llamando bien la librería que estas utilizando del PDF

Comment: @Oswuell Cuando la usaba en localhost funcionaba. ¿Como hago ahora una verificación?

Comment: ¿Estas corriendo desde un hosting?

Comment: @Oswuell Uso concretamente 000webhost.